# Как сделать "галочку" в главном меню приложения WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Собственно, хочу в WinForms приложении сделать переключаемую галочку в главном меню. Скажите, можно ли (и если можно, то каким образом) сделать это встроенными средствами Visual Studio (2008 редакция). Чтобы было понятнее, привожу скриншот желаемого результата на примере программы uTorrent.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (showIcon == false)
    {
        toolStripMenuItem2.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("d:\\pic.bmp");//рисовать галочку
        showIcon = true;
        //сделать действие
    }
    else
    {
        toolStripMenuItem2.Image = null;
        showIcon = false;
        //сделать действие
    }
}
```

pic.bmp (или .ico, .jpg)- картинка с галочкой. При нажатии пункта меню рисуем галочку и делаем какое-то действие (например, изменяем нужный параметр на 1). При повторном нажатии убираем галочку и делаем другое действие (например, изменяем нужный параметр на 0).

"По просьбе трудящихся" вместо быдлокодерского варианта предлагается кошерный вариант :)

```
private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripMenuItem2.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        toolStripMenuItem2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
    }
    else
    {
        toolStripMenuItem2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Как и предполагал, придётся вставлять картинку. Жаль, что нет встроенных средств для данного действия.
Кстати, можно не открывать внешний файл с иконкой, а просто добавить его в ресурсы и потом присваивать:
toolStripMenuItem2.Image = global::ImyaProekta.Properties.Resources.Image5;

Comment: Ужас. Есть свойство [ToolStripMenuItem.CheckState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.checkstate.aspx).

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: AlexeyM, спасибо, исправился :)